# 引数がRef*の場合とそうでない場合で処理をわけるテンプレート関数

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

自作クラスでテンプレート関数を作り、
引数valueがRef*の場合とそうでない場合で処理を変えたいと思っています。

valueの型がint,float,double,std::string,boolなどの場合は_valueMapに格納し、
Ref*の場合は_objectMapに格納するようにしたいです。

```
class MyClass : public cocos2d::Ref
{
private:
    cocos2d::ValueMap _valueMap;
    cocos2d::Map<std::string, cocos2d::Ref*> _objectMap;
public:
    template <typename T>
    inline void addValue(T value, const std::string& key);

    template <typename T>
    inline T getValue(const std::string& key);
}

template <typename T>
inline void MyClass::addValue(T value, const std::string& key)
{
    _valueMap[key] = value;
}
tempalte <>
inline void MyClass::addValue(cocos2d::Ref* value, const std::string& key)
{
    if (value) {
        _objectMap.insert(key, value);
    }
}
```

ところがこのコードだと、RefのサブクラスであるNodeや、その他の自作クラスのポインタをvalueとして渡したときに、特殊化した関数が呼ばれず、_valueMapのほうに格納されてしまいます。

関数を呼ぶときにaddValue＜Ref*＞とすれば大丈夫なのですが、書き忘れが怖いです。

Ref*の場合とそれ以外で関数を分けるしかないのでしょうか。

編集：
回答ありがとうございます。
Ref*の他に、TがVec2の場合の特殊化をするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

```
template <>
inline void addValue<cocos2d::Vec2>(const cocos2d::Vec2& value, const std::string& key)
{
    _vec2Map[key] = value;
}
```

と書いたらNo function template matches function template specializationというエラーになりました。
enable_ifの条件を追加して、Vec2の場合にも非テンプレート関数を書くしかないのでしょうか。

編集：
解決しました。

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass : public cocos2d::Ref
{   
    std::unordered_map<std::string, cocos2d::Vec2> _vec2Map;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, cocos2d::Size> _sizeMap;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, cocos2d::Rect> _rectMap;
    cocos2d::ValueMap _valueMap;
    cocos2d::Map<std::string, cocos2d::Ref*> _objectMap;
public:
    template <typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, cocos2d::Ref*>::value,
    std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
    inline void addValue(T value, const std::string& key)
    {
        CCLOG("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        _valueMap[key] = value;
    }

    void addValue(cocos2d::Ref* value, const std::string& key)
    {
        CCLOG("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        if (value) {
            _objectMap.insert(key, value);
        }
    }
};
#include "MyClass_Private.h"
```

MyClass_Private.h

```
#include "MyClass.h"

template <>
inline void MyClass::addValue<cocos2d::Vec2,nullptr>
(cocos2d::Vec2 value, const std::string& key)
{
    _vec2Map[key] = value;
}
template <>
inline void MyClass::addValue<cocos2d::Size,nullptr>
(cocos2d::Size value, const std::string& key)
{
    _sizeMap[key] = value;
}
template <>
inline void MyClass::addValue<cocos2d::Rect,nullptr>
(cocos2d::Rect value, const std::string& key)
{
    _rectMap[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++にはSFINAEという仕組みがあります。テンプレートの置き換えに失敗してもエラーにならないようにするとかなんとか。
またそれをうまく利用するために`std::enable_if`他のテンプレートが用意されています。
これらを使うと「TがRefやサブクラスの場合にはaddValue()テンプレート関数が定義されていなかったこと」にできます。その上で改めてaddValue(Ref*,)を非テンプレート関数として用意してやればいいでしょう。

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of<Ref, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value>* = nullptr>
void addValue(T value, const std::string& key) {
    //
}
void addValue(Ref* value, const std::string& key) {
    //
}
```

古いコンパイラーだと次のように記述する必要があるかもしれません。

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Ref, typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::value>::type
addValue(T value, const std::string& key) {
    //
}
```

---

元質問は

> valueの型がint,float,double,std::string,boolなどの場合は_valueMapに格納し、
>   Ref*の場合は_objectMapに格納するようにしたいです。

でしたが追加質問では逆転していて、`Ref*`、`Vec2`、`Size`、`Rect`の場合は`_objectMap`で、残りが`_valueMap`と受け取れます。

であれば`enable_if`の型パラメーターはbool式ですので希望する式を記述すれば実現できます。

```
// Refかその派生型へのポインター、Vec2、Size、Rectのいずれか
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_pointer<T>::value && std::is_base_of<Ref, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value
    || std::is_same<Vec2, T>::value
    || std::is_same<Size, T>::value
    || std::is_same<Rect, T>::value
>* = nullptr>
void addValue(T value, const std::string& key) {
    //
}
// それ以外
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<
    !(std::is_pointer<T>::value && std::is_base_of<Ref, std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value
    || std::is_same<Vec2, T>::value
    || std::is_same<Size, T>::value
    || std::is_same<Rect, T>::value)
>* = nullptr>
void addValue(T value, const std::string& key) {
    //
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Ref*の他に、TがVec2の場合の特殊化をするにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか

Comment: わかりにくくてすみません。
Ref*、Vec2、Size、Rectのそれぞれについて、_objectMap、_vec2Map、_sizeMap、_rectMapに格納したいです。
（Vec2,Size,RectはValueMapに入らないので）
質問に追記したやり方で実装したのですが、is_sameで比較する方法だと、例えばconst Vec2を渡したときに正しく格納されなくなりませんか？

Comment: @noprops あぁすみません、コードを見れていませんでした。何であれ、必要なオーバーロードを用意していけばいいかと。また`const`を付けたいのであれば`remove_const`した上で比較すればいいです。

Comment: @noprops やはり質問がだんだんと変化していて当初と異なる内容が求められているように感じられます。型ごとに対応した異なる処理を求めるというのであれば、`type traits`も視野に入ってきます。